# How to set the scene to be leftmost in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt Creator to create an application that can draw a strip according to given input. I'm drawing this using QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsRectItem with the container which is a Graphics View. However, after calling the draw function, I got something looks like this:
[Window for drawing strips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VneYh.png)

The x value for all strips are 0, and those strips showed up in the middle of the container. What I really want it to draw the strip so that when the x value is 0, it is proximate to the left side of the container. Any idea about how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like parent element (`QGraphicsScene`) decides the position of the child element (`QGraphicsRectItem`).  You have to check the positioning properties of parent elements in scenarios like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates of the scene elements are given in the scene coordinate system. Each view transforms the scene coordinates to the view coordinates. You need to set the transformation to map the scene *x=0* to view *x=0*. If the full scene is visible, all it takes is to set proper alignment:

```
view.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
```